# sql server encrypted column to be decrypted on another server

Tags: sql-server-2005, sql-server-2008, encryption

[How to: Encrypt a Column of Data](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms179331.aspx) shows how to encrypt a column of data in sql server and decrypt it **in the same database instance** the encryption part is exactly what I want however the decryption process would be different for me :

I will create csv files from the tables with encrypted column and will import these files into another instance of sql server where the other server should be able to decrypt .

A. how can I do the encryption on server A and do the decryption on server B ? (is it possible to send the other server the certificate file ?)

B.the encryptor server is sql server 2008 can we do the decryption on sql server 2005 or develop .net module for doing the decryption ?

Answer (score 1):

OK I found the answer [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms366281.aspx) for part A .

and for part B the answer is yes the decryption can be done in sql 2005 and I just did it .